# Google Chrome App usb api

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm new to making a Google Chrome App using the Chrome Dev editor.

I created a default project and just did a console.log(chrome.usb) in the default js file and it's shows chrome.usb is undefined.

How do I access the chrome.usb api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `"usb"` permission and the devices you want to access.

Any API that requires a permission shows up as undefined if you don't have it.

See [Manifest requirement](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#manifest).

Since it's not clear:

```
"permissions" : [
  "usb",
  {
    "usbDevices": [ 
     { "vendorId": 7419, "productId": 4112 } ] } 
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I literally pasted that into the manifest, nested with the default stuff. When I open the inspector/console and type chrome.usb and hit enter and it says undefined.  
`code
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Scanner",
....

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  
  "permissions": [
    {
      "usbDevices": [
        {
          "vendorId": 7419,
          "productId": 4112
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
code`

Comment: 1) Never put code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question instead. 2) Your manifest is wrong. It does not have `"usb"` permission, and it must be there.

Comment: Ok sorry, was trying to fix it.  :)

Comment: So when I copy past the permissions with only usb in it, the usb variable is defined.  However I must declare the devices....So I then copy and paste the second permissions in below and chrome.usb is once again undefined.  :(  I tried to combine them and get a yellow warning triangle saying usbDevices must be an object...What am I not getting?

Comment: That `"permissions"` is an array. It can contain the string `"usb"` and the object. Comma-separated.

Comment: I guess I'm still not seeing a way to incorporate the permissions of the specific product/vendor id's into the json.  I do understand the formatting of json.  But I get a warning if I stick anything but a string in the permissions array.  But in the documentation it says to use usbDevices object... I have to explicitly list the vendor and product....so it's like say yes and no at the same time...

Comment: Oh..I see.  it all make sense now. /facepalm.  Why don't they just stick that in their example?  Here I am trying to put usbDevices as a string equal to an array and it wants an object with the string equal to an array.  :( Thanks

Comment: Don'r forget to reload the app after the changes ;)